# Hidden input data is not passed from view component to post action method in controller - ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to pass parameters value from a view component to a post action method, but the hidden input is not received in the controller.

I know how to pass from view to controller and it works fine, but in the view component it is not passed to action.

This is component for show images in `Edit` view:

```
public class EditPostImageComponent: ViewComponent
{
    private IPostService _postService;

    public EditPostImageComponent(IPostService postService)
    {
        _postService = postService;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(ShowPostListItemViewModel showPostListItemViewModel)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult((IViewComponentResult)View("EditPostImage", _postService.GetPostGallary(showPostListItemViewModel.PostId)));
    }
}
```

This is view component for displaying images:

```
@model List<DataLayer.Models.ViewModels.Post.ShowPostListItemViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{   
     <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4">      
     @if (item.ImageName != null)
     {
         <form method="post" asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Post" asp-action="DeletePostImg">
             <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.PostId" />
             <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Title" />
             <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Description" />
             <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.ImageName" />

             <div class="blog-item position-relative overflow-hidden rounded mb-2">
                 <img id="imgPost" class="img-fluid thumbnail" src="/img/post/@item.Title/@item.ImageName" alt="">
                 <br />
                 <br />
                 @*<a asp-controller="Post" asp-action="DeletePostImg" 
                      asp-route-id="@item.PostId" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>*@
                 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="Delete" />
             </div>
         </form>
        }   
        else
        { 
             <div class="blog-item position-relative overflow-hidden rounded mb-2">  
               <img id="imgAvatar" class="thumbnail" src="/UserAvatar/Defult.jpg" />          
            </div> 
        }
    </div>
```

This is action method for delete images from database directly.

```
[HttpPost]
public void DeletePostImg(ShowPostListItemViewModel showPostListItemViewModel)
{
    _postService.DeletePostImage(showPostListItemViewModel);
}
```

When I debug, I get a null or zero value for input hidden fields. in view,in similar circumstances these parameters is sent to the controller correctly.

Where is the problem from? Please help me

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could press F12 to check the name attribute of the input box,in your case,the name was `item.PostId` but in your controller the name of the parameter is `showPostListItemViewModel` ,the name don't match,so it bind failed

[image]

You could try  as below in your view component:

```
@foreach (var showPostListItemViewModel in Model)
{
    <form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Post">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@showPostListItemViewModel.PostId">
        <br />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@showPostListItemViewModel.Description">
        <div class="blog-item position-relative overflow-hidden rounded mb-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
}
```

The Result:

[image]